# Problem with file-systemy on github - Discord.Js

Tags: github, discord.js

I'm doing my discord bot with **discord.js**. I've host it with **GitHub **and** Heroku**. When a user send a command, the bot **write** some information on a **txt file**. Locally that's working but when i'm host it on github and heroku, the bot doesnt write correctly, dont write on github's files, so on github the files are **empty** and when I **restart** the bot that reset all

Thanks

Comment: How do you host it on GitHub **and** Heroku?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Yes, I connect heroku to Github

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. That means that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for persistent storage of data.

A solution to this issue is to use [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), which is free.